# multiple unique clients using socket.io and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am working with socket.io and express, and I am struggling with having unique pages that all send and recieve messages from the server.

When I follow most tutorials, the server script starts out with something like this:

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var clients = {};

app.listen(8080);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

and I can test my client app at localhost:8080. But what I want is to run a multiple client apps at something like http://localhost:8080/myApp/client1.html and http://localhost:8080/myApp/client2.html. When I try this, it returns something like:

```
Cannot GET /myApp/client1.html
```

My goal is to have two or more unique pages that can send messages to each other via sockets. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have been banging my head on this for way too long now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Express but instinct tells me get() would refer to a GET HTTP request and thus not a websocket. I think you're supposed to use Express to return HTML for page requests but real-time data transfer would be handled by Socket.io.

So, you would have Express return for the actual page requests:

```
app.get('/myApp/client1.html', function(blah){});
app.get('/myApp/client2.html', function(blah){});
```

Then [socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) would handle the talking:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('msg', function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit('msg', {msg: data.msg});
  });
});
```

Client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('msg', function (data) {
  //code to add data.msg somewhere on page
});
somebutton.on('click', function(e){
  socket.emit('msg', {msg:$(e.targetElement).value()});
});
```

Again, I don't know Express so I may have the syntax wrong but my gist is that you have two things going on that you need to handle separately. One is the returning of actual HTML pages, the other is the real-time data communication between the loaded pages. My examples are crude, check the Socket.io [Readme](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io) for some better examples.

Comment: Thank you! You directed my attention to the right place (the first parameter of app.get() ). That is all I needed to solve my problem.

Comment: Do I need to use Express for this? If not, what do I replace the express code with to allow socket communication across different html pages?

Comment: You shouldn't need express for just socket communication. The example I provided is a very basic chat room and I mostly copied it from the socket.io examples. You can pretty much copy the examples from the socket.io website to at least have something to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have tried those examples and may others that are very similar. I can get all of them to work, but where I get lost is as soon as I move into multiple html files and I understand the socket communication part. The problem for me is, all the examples either do not have an html page, or they just use index.html. None of them use multiple html pages that load additional files with relative paths.

Comment: BTW, thank you for your help. I'm on track now and now know enough to build out all my current socket server projects. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

or add a dynamic handler for your files:

```
app.get('/myApp/:file', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname+'/'+req.param('file'));
});
```

or beef it up a little with a regex:

```
app.get(/^\/myApp\/(.+)\.html$/, function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname+'/'+req.params[0]);
});
```

Comment: Hey Brad. I'm not sure I understand your implantation but I think you are hitting on the issue I am dealing with now. The answer from XHR helped me solve my initial question, but now it appears as if I need to add an app.get() for every file I want to load. I would prefer something more dynamic, which I think is what you are suggesting, but I was not able to get either of your suggestions to work. I think what I would like to do is request all files in myApp, so that my HTML page can load anything it wants from myApp without adding a request for each file in the server script.

Comment: that's exactly what you can do with a dynamic route.  What exactly wasn't working when you tried to do it?  It might just be an implementation detail.

Comment: It looks like the html pages load with the following script, but the files that the html pages reference do not.
// Server Script
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(8080);

app.get('/myApp/:file', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname+'/'+req.param('file'));
});

// HTML Page 
 
<img src="images/bkg.png" />
 
 // or
 
<img src="/myApp/images/bkg.png" />

Comment: err, sorry, I didn't realize the all the line breaks would be removed. If there is a cleaner way I can send you the above comment, let me know.

Comment: ah, so it looks like it does not go into sub directories. I added the following and it works now. app.get('/myApp/:file', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname+'/'+req.param('file'));
});
app.get('/myApp/images/:file', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname+'/images/'+req.param('file'));
});

Comment: BTW, thank you for your help. I'm on track now and now know enough to build out all my current socket server projects. Cheers!

Comment: you should add a the connect/express "static" middleware to handle images instead of serving them with that handler fyi.